# Android Jetpack Navigation Component too slow. What's the problem?

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, android-jetpack-navigation

Today I was changing from `ViewPager` to `Navigation Component` (with `Bottom Navigation View`) on my Android project. The problem is that, when using `ViewPager` all is fast as lightning but using `Navigation Component` it's very laggy (2 seconds later after you pressed the view appears and specially with `RecyclerView` fragments).

Is there any way to pre-load fragments and improve transitions?

Thanks in advance !

---

**MainActivity.java**

```
NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(binding.bottomBar, navController);
```

Comment: With a viewpager you can preload the neighboring screens, while the nav component will create the fragments after you've selected it. So it looks like the lag is in the inflation of your fragments, you may be doing too much work on inflation.

Comment: Yes but, when using a ViewPager there's no lag even when I start the app (that's when I suppose the fragment inflates). There's a huge difference on UX.

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same issue. I believe its a bug in their latest dependency.

Changing to `androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.4` and `androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.4` solved my issue.

Might also work for higher versions than 2.3.4. I haven't checked yet.